# Где в приложении указывать версию приложения?

Tags: java, android

Где в приложении нужно прописывать версию приложения? в `values/strings`? в `values/dimens`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в `build.gradle` есть поля - `version_name` `version_code`.
`version_name` отвечает за юзеро-читабельную версию, например `1.0.3`
`version_code` отвечает за *номер версии*, и является числом типа `int`. Когда вы загружаете в Google Play обновление, это число должно быть больше, чем в предыдущей версии